# How to prove using mathematical induction that $25\mid2^{n+1}\cdot 3^n + 30n -4$?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, induction

How to prove using mathematical induction that $25\mid 2^{n+1}\cdot3^n +30n -4$?

Comment: It is not clear to me what you mean?

Comment: Please edit to include your efforts.  Also:  why write $30-4$ instead of $26$?

Comment: This does not work even for $n=0$.

Comment: Note:  if $n=1 $ you are asking to prove that $25$ divides $32$.

Comment: Gonna be very hard to prove. It will require earth-shattering mathematics. Or maybe you copied the problem wrong? Another hint something weird is happening: $+30-4$ can be written as $+26,$ so it seems unlikely that was the problem intended.

Comment: yes, my mistake I edited the topic

Comment: still wrong: $n=1$ says $25 | 38$ ?

Answer (score 2):

It's not, for any natural number because the number on the right will always end with 8.